# Find similar documents between two piles of documents

Tags: linux, windows, comparison, file-comparison

I am looking for ways to find similar documents between two group of text documents. I know ways to compare two files. But I am looking for ways to do that between two group of files.

Let's say Group 1 has 100,000 documents, and Group 2 has 5000 documents. I want to know if any document in Group 2 is similar to documents in Group 1, and the similarity score.

Thanks for any advice.

B

Comment: Similarity based on what? Name? Type? File Size? Contents?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume you care about the file "content". Determining files that are identical is easy, any duplication finder will do the trick:

1. GNU/Linux: `find . ! -empty -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort | uniq -w32 -dD`
2. GNU/Linux: [fdupes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fdupes) (often available with `sudo apt install fdupes`)
3. GNU/Linux: [duff](http://duff.dreda.org/) (often available with `sudo apt install duff`
4. Windows: [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)
5. Windows: [dupeGuru](https://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru/) [1]
6. Windows: [Duplicate File Remover](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/duplicate-file-remover/9nblggh4sqnp)

For "Similar" files in general, it gets tougher -- a lot tougher. If you are looking for similar photos/images, check out [How can I find duplicate photos in a very large pool of data (tens to hundreds of gigs)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26026/how-can-i-find-duplicate-photos-in-a-very-large-pool-of-data-tens-to-hundreds-o). `dupeGuru` above has an image similarity search which some think is OK, but it will miss some that you might think are nearly identical (or identical). In fact, stenographically altered images will look identical to you but not to a file-comparing algorithm. Some image processing AI will do well with these, but I'm assuming you don't want to build one of those.

Now for the really bad news: if you want to look for all sorts of files that are "similar" but not identical such as text files, PDFs, ZIP files, etc. you will have to find specific handlers for each and you may not be happy with the results even after a lot of work.

Why? Let's look at two Microsoft Word documents as an example: one with "Hello World" and the other "Hello world!" ("W" -> "w" and an "!" added). I would assume you'd want these to have a very high similarity score. Unfortunately they can be radically different (>90% of bytes) if one version was from 1997 and the other from 2007 or if the meta-information is different, or the format has changed. But if you had a process that extracted only the text from the files, then you'd be much better able to deal with this, you would just have to deal with the complexities of text-differences (lowercase everything, remove punctuation and white-space, and then compare?).

Similarly, if you have two **identical** PDF files in terms of how they look when you open them up, they could still be >90% different at the byte level if one has fonts embedded, all meta-information added, and image previews embedded while the other is stripped down to only the things needed for printing and assumes the system has all the fonts.

Last example: Compressed files of any kind. For a number of common algorithms used, tiny changes in the file, particularly early in the file, can have dramatic changes to the bytes that are written to disk. So here too, you would have to uncompress the file(s), potentially recursively, and then compare. And in that case, do you want reported back the compressed file comparison or the uncompressed file(s) comparison of the contained information? Note that many file formats used lossy or lossless compression in part or all of the files.

In short, unless you have thousands of files in nearly **identical format** you may be looking at a very long project.